# Proving that supremum is $\frac{9}{8}$ of set $D = \{\frac{n^2}{2^n}~|~n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I've show that $\frac{9}{8}$ is an upper bound, but am struggling with showing that it is the least upper bound, or rather how  $\frac{a^2}{2^a} > \frac{9}{8} - \epsilon$ shows that $\frac{9}{8}$ is a least upper bound. My proof as is:

We first prove the inequality $2^n \geq n^2$ for $n \geq 4$. We do so by mathematical induction. For the basis step let $n = 4$. Then 
\begin{align*}
2^{(4)} &\geq (4)^2 \\
16 &\geq 16.
\end{align*}

Thus, $n  = 4$ holds true. Now assume that the statement is true for some $n = k \geq 4$. That is, $k^2 \leq 2^k$. This implies that $n = k+1$ is true. Then

\begin{align*}
2^{k+1} &= 2 \cdot 2^k  \\
&\geq 2 \cdot k^2 \tag{By Induction Hypothesis}\\
& \geq k^2 + 2k + 1 \\
& \geq (k+1)^2.
\end{align*}

Hence, $2^{k+1} \geq (k+1)^2$. Therefore, it follows that $2^n \geq n^2$. Thus, when $n=3$ we have that $\frac{9}{8}$ is an upper bound of $A$. Since $\frac{9}{8}$ is an upper bound of A we have for any $a \in A$ that $a \leq \frac{9}{8}$. Now, suppose sup$(A) = \frac{9}{8}$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0, \frac{9}{8} - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Hence, $\frac{a^2}{2^a} > \frac{9}{8} - \epsilon$.

Comment: If you have an upper bound that is also an element of the set, you are already done.

Comment: BTW, if you enter the realm of real analysis, the function $f(x)=x^2/2^x$ achieves it's maximum for positive $x$ at $x=2/\ln(2)\approx 2.8854$.

Comment: @String After reiterating over the definition, what you've said does make sense indeed. I was assuming that for $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ that for upper bound $M \in \mathbb{R}$ that $M$ was always in A, which of course isn't the case. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: $9/8$ is the maximum of $D$, therefore is the supremum of $D$.